# JavaScript - Create New Object (Function) Using an object literal?

Tags: javascript, object

I have a function defined in my JavaScript with two properties: `size` and `url`:

```
function IconInfo() {
    this.size = size;
    this.url = url;
}
```

Inside another function I create a new instance of `IconInfo` and set the properties this way:

```
function SomeFunction() {
    var icon = new IconInfo();
    icon.size = 64;
    icon.url = "http://somesite.com/image1.png";
}
```

Isn't there a way to create an instance like the following:

```
  var icon = new IconInfo({
      size : 64,
      url  : "http://somesite.com/image1.png"
  });
```

I like that notation better, it seems more concise and easier to read.

===========================*UPDATE*================================

Based on Tim's answer of doing it the following way:

```
var icon = {
  size : 64,
  url  : "http://somesite.com/image1.png"
};
```

I have the following question.

Let's say I have 2 functions both with the same exact properties and constructor arguments:

```
function Func1(x) {
    this.x = x;
}

function Func2(x) {
    this.x = x;
}
```

And I have a container that holds either type:

```
function Container() {
    this.f = null;
}
```

If I add one of the functions using that method what type will it actually be?

```
...
var container = new Container();
container.x = new f { // is f Func1 or Func2?
    x: 10;
}
```

Comment: The term [*"type"*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8) has a defined meaning in ECMAScript that is inconsistent with your use. You are using it more like "class", but [*`[[Class]]`*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.6.2) has a different meaning too. So you really mean to ask "how can I distinguish between an instance of Func1 and Func2". Look at the [*instanceof*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.8.6) operator, or perhaps the object's *constructor* property, but there are issues with both approaches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a lot of options, but keeping it simple.. you could just do this:

```
var icon = {
  size : 64,
  url  : "http://somesite.com/image1.png"
};
```

You don't have to declare a "type", but you could.. sort of like this:

```
function IconInfo(size, url)
  this.size = size;
  this.url = url;
);
var icon = new IconInfo(2, "www.google.com");
```

Comment: I read something like that on another search site but I wasn't sure how the "compiler" knows that when you create a new icon (as in your first example) what type it is?

Comment: The javascript "compiler" doesn't care if you have a strongly defined type.  You can put any property you want on an object.  For instance.. `var obj = {}` ... `obj.prop = 2`.  That's not to say that it's not a good idea to strongly define a type, but that's another discussion entirely.

Comment: What if I have another function that has the same exact properties: size and url then I do a new blah = { size: 64, etc...} how would it know to which type I am referring?

Comment: is it important to know the type?  Could you assume that the type you're getting has the properties you need?  You could check for the existence of those properties via `if(obj.prop) .. do something ..`

Comment: Better to use `if (obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)) ...` as `obj.prop` will return false for a number of values when the property exists but has a falsey value.

Comment: I am pretty sure I know what you mean... I updated my question to show an example of what I mean. I have 2 functions Func1 and Func2 and another that contains references one via the variable f. If I create a new function without setting the type then how is it determined what the type of f is?

Comment: I guess what I'm not understanding is why you think it's important to know the type of the object.  In javascript, objects don't need to have a type, or rather, they are of type `Object`.  You can assign any property you want to an `Object`.

Answer (score 1):

You can actually make it even more concise. First, you're forgetting to set the variables inside `IconInfo`; it should be this:

```
function IconInfo(size, url) {
    this.size = size;
    this.url = url;
}
```

To create a new `IconInfo` in your other function, you'll just need to call it like this:

```
function SomeFunction() {
    var icon = new IconInfo(64, "http://somesite.com/image1.png");
}
```

Comment: Yes, I realized just now that I was forgetting to set the variables. But more generally I just wanted to know if there was a way to create an object using the "json" type syntax of new SomeType({x:"x", y:"y", etc.}); and also what using that syntax is called anyway? I know I am calling it "json" syntax which is probably totally stupid. :)